# Show only 100 samples in Graph

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array that is printed in a javascript graph. Now is taken the first measurement until the last measurement. I wan't to display the first 100 measurements and if the measurements get over 100 (lets say 130) to display measurement 30 until 130, etc. How can I fix this in my code?

```
    <?php  
    for ($x = 0; $x < (count($data) - 1); $x++) {
       if($x % 5  == 0){
         //echo $x; //5th element
         $row = $data[$x];
         $time = intval($row->{'time'});
         echo $x;
       } else{
         echo ' '; //prints empty for other than 5th element
       }
       echo ', '; //prints ',' for every element
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the start of your code to:

```
$total=count($data);

if($total>100){
   $start= $total-100;
}else{
   $start=0;
}


for ($x = $start; $x <= $total; $x++) {
```